# How to increase Hangfire timeout in Version 1.6 using MysqlStorage

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, hangfire

I am using Hangfire in my ASP Net Core Project and using Mysql as storage.

I have a long running task which runs for about 1 hour. But the default Timeout for hangfire is 30 minutes. hence that task is ran again.

I wanted to use `InvisibilityTimeout` but its obsolete. Any suggestions?

I did try to use `JobExpirationCheckInterval` but I dont know if its the right one.

Any pointing in the right direction is appericiated.

Answer (score -1):

I set InvisibilityTimeout and JobExpirationCheckInterval to 1 day and it seems to work.